# How to get Liquibase serveroutput

Tags: liquibase

How to get serveroutput for sql scripts using liquibase with springboot ?.

I have already tried 'set serveroutput on', but this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use SQLPlus integration with Liquibase and then you can set serveroutput to ON. Documentation can be found here: https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/advanced/runwith.html

You can read a blog about it here: https://www.liquibase.com/blog/using-sqlplus-liquibase